# register_blueprint doesn't add route to Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I created a blueprint with a route and registered the blueprint with my Flask app.  However, I get a 404 when requesting the route.  What is wrong with my code?

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('test', __name__)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(test_blueprint, url_prefix='/test')

@bp.route('/')
def home_route():
    return "This is the home route."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2016 13:54:19] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You registered the blueprint before the code that registered the route executed.  Move `register_blueprint` after the blueprint has been fully defined.

```
bp = Blueprint('test', __name__, url_prefix='/test')

@bp.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello, World!'

app.register_blueprint(bp)
```